# How do I find back a commit in Git?

Tags: git

Here's what I did..

- I checked out a previous commit (2 commits ago)
- I modified files
- Committed those files
- Accidentally went back to the master branch

How do I get back to the files I committed without knowing the commit id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the reflog for HEAD. Two ways of doing so:

- `git reflog show HEAD` ([manpage](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html))
- Or open the text file `./git/logs/HEAD`

This will show you the commits that you recently made, no matter what branch (or lack thereof) they are in.

Suppose you found the lost commit and its hash is `0123ab`. You can either checkout it (`git checkout 0123ab`), or your can merge it into master (`git checkout master`; `git merge 0123ab`).

Comment: You're a star! Even with the instaweb command I couldn't find any reference of my commit.. but above command gave it to me right away. One to remember. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I appreciate your clearly worded question, especially your procedure.

Comment: Yup, I had to wait for the 10 minutes to pass.. thanks again :)

Comment: Ohh! I didn't know that restriction. Interesting.